# Having trouble importing products in magento with magmi

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am trying to import products into magento wth the magmi product importer but the import just sits there. Why would this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: There must be some log docs you can read, showing what failed.

Comment: Yes there are I just wasn't given access to where they are located at the beginning of my import project. I hope they can be of some help when I get in and take a look because right now I cannot tell what the problem is.

Comment: So they forked a development clone of the actual production virtual machine, but they didn't gave you root access to that development clone.